# update value of col1 based on col2 condition in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

### here is my question.

### DF:

- Col1   |  Col2        | col1_updated
- 10    | mango_orange  |10*2
- 32     | apple_Banana | 32*3
- 26     | Onion        | 26*4

---

if col2 contain mango update col1 value*2, if apple multiply  by 3, onion multiply by 4.

---

I have used map function but that looks lengthy when cases are more.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's your code? It is difficult to help with your code issues if you do not show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[df['col2'].str.contains('apple'), 'col1'] = df['col1'] * 2
```

OR [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col2'].str.contains('apple'), df['col1'] * 2, df['col1'])
```

NOTE: You can pass case=False in contains if you want the case of values to be ignored

Comment: what if we have more than 2 cases like : if apple contains than multiply by 2 ; orange contain than multiply by 3; mango contain then multiply by 4

Comment: @amitaanand you can provide a pattern in place of apple.

Comment: You can read about pandas contains here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: @amitaanand update the question with the required output